# How can I change the Background color and the Font size in Apache J Meter

Tags: fonts, jmeter, background

How can I change the background color to White from the existing Black color and also increase the font size of the Apache J Meter Software?

Answer (score 13):

1. [Starting from JMeter 2.6 the theme can be chosen from `Options -> Look and Feel`](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-26-new-gui) entry of the JMeter Main Menu:

   [image]
2. Fonts can be zoomed in/out by holding `CONTROL` and `ALT` and turning the mouse wheel. Another option is again choosing `Options -> Zoom In` from JMeter main menu:

   [image]

For fine tuning/choosing fonts/making changes permanent/etc. you can play with [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.laf=CrossPlatform "-Dswing.plaf.metal.userFont=Comic Sans MS-40"
```